# Importing sobj sage objects?

Tags: import, interoperability

I am working with a [sage-math object](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/structure/sage/structure/sage_object.html). With some older versions of *Mathematica* it was possible to send data directly but [the function doesn't work with Mathematica 9](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/13892).

What are my options to import a sobj object into newer versions of *Mathematica*?

Comment: Yes, I know this is old but I think it's an important question. Most people on this site don't have experience with Sage. I think a solution needs at least as much (if not more) Sage expertise as Mathematica knowledge.  It would be helpful if you added more details about what Sage itself can do, what it can export to, what data structures you want to export, most importantly what a `sage-math` object is. I believe (correct me if I'm wrong)    that Sage pipes textual input/output to/from Mathematica which is a horrible way to interface with Mma. The proper way would be somethign MathLink-based.

Comment: Unfortunately there might be obstacles in the way of implementing a MathLink-based interface.  A practical one is that the Sage community appears (to me) to be particularly un-welcoming towards Mathematica (or any other non-free software) due to it not being open source.  A legal one is that it would require linking to the MathLink libraries which are not open source.  Sage uses the GPL and even pushed for making more permissive LGPL-components strictly GPL (search for "GMP forked" and note that many commercial CAS use GMP under the LGPL).

Comment: While I am personally interested in Sage and I try it from time to time, I would not personally try to create such a MathLink interface between Sage and Mathematica: it is a lot of work and due to the general attitude many Sage users and developers have I fully expect the GPL issue to come up at some point.

Comment: Many people release scientific software libraries under the GPL without realizing that this prevents people from distributing ready to use glue software that links the library against closed source systems like Mathematica and MATLAB.  I've seen library authors even encouraging such linking.  I'm worried that with Sage this would not go so easily.

Comment: @Szabolcs Any chance of transfer by way of MathML? That is, Sage --> MathML --> Mathematica (using Import for that last step).